# for_each algorithm to loop over boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, templates, boost, namespaces, boost-multi-array

Related questions have been asked here before, but I still haven't found a satisfactory answer, so I will try to explain my problem and hope someone can enlighten me.

I am currently writing some code using boost::multi_array, and the code itself is also dimension independent. I need to loop over all elements stored in the multi_array and do something with them. I am looking to do this in a STL-like way:

```
for_each(begin(array), end(array), function);
```

Or something similar. Other questions have pointed me to an example on the boost page itself:

[for_each example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/example/foreach_test.cpp)
[for_each implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/example/for_each.hpp)

Which is more or less exactly what I want. The problem comes when one tries to simply import this code into a larger program. One would naturally like to both wrap the function itself in some namespace, and use for example the C++ functionals as the function object. Doing any of these two will create template lookup problems for the compiler.

Does anyone know either how I can work around the template lookup issue, or an alternative way of doing it (that is hopefully as pretty)?

Additional info:

Compilation error when wrapping the for_each definitions in a namespace

```
./for_each.hpp:28:3: error: call to function 'for_each' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by
argument-dependent lookup
  for_each(type_dispatch,A.begin(),A.end(),xform);
  ^
./for_each.hpp:41:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'boost_utilites::for_each<boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<double, 1>,
      double, times_five>' requested here
    for_each(type_dispatch,*begin,xform);
    ^
./for_each.hpp:50:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost_utilites::for_each<double,
      boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<double, double *, mpl_::size_t<2>, boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<double,
1>,
      boost::random_access_traversal_tag>, times_five>' requested here
  for_each(boost::type<typename Array::element>(),A.begin(),A.end(),xform);
  ^
foreach_test.cpp:46:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'boost_utilites::for_each<boost::multi_array<double, 2,
      std::allocator<double> >, times_five>' requested here
  boost_utilites::for_each(A,times_five());
                  ^
./for_each.hpp:37:6: note: 'for_each' should be declared prior to the call site or in an associated namespace of one of its
arguments
void for_each (const boost::type<Element>& type_dispatch,
     ^
1 error generated.
```

When using a std::function object instead of the times_five object in the example, one gets basically the same compilation error.

Compiled with clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
std::for_each(array.data(), array.data() + array.num_elements(), function);
```

To make it work with functions that expect an random-access range (with `.begin()`, `.end()` and `.size()`) use

```
auto elements = boost::make_iterator_range(array.data(), array.data() + array.num_elements();

// e.g.
for (auto& element : elements) {

    ...
}
```

I personally like to use this with `generate_n` or `fill_n` etc.:

```
std::for_each(array.data(), array.num_elements(), 0);
```

---

Reference [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#idp18501744)

> - `element* data();`
> - `const element* data() const;`
>
>   This returns a pointer to the beginning of the contiguous block that
>     contains the array's data. If all dimensions of the array are
>     0-indexed and stored in ascending order, this is equivalent to
>     origin(). Note that const_multi_array_ref only provides the const
>     version of this function.

and

> - `size_type a.num_elements()`
>
>   This returns the number of elements contained in the array. It is equivalent to the following code:
>
>   ```
>   std::accumulate(a.shape(),a.shape+a.num_dimensions(), 
>              size_type(1),std::multiplies<size_type>());>
>   ```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed seem to do what I want. Specially thanks for the tip on the make_iterator_range, that did make things a bit prettier. I have always preferred not to directly access the underlying containers of these data structures, such as calling std::vector::data. But with the iterator_range you can at least wrap the data access away and hide it.